# Python Threading Tkinter: Why does the second launch of a thread not functioning properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am Trying to learn how to host a second helper window to host some data while I'm working in the terminal.  Part of this involves changing the window's contents periodically and I want the second window not to jam up the main process.  So I am hoping to be able to launch the tkinter text as a thread.

Below is what I have currently.  The first time the launch thread is called, the tkinter textbox comes up, and once it is closed, the thread joins.  On the second launch, the window is not created and you can see that the "After start" is never called.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
>>> import threading
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> def build_textbox():
    root = tk.Tk()
    T= tk.Text(root, height=100, width=100)
    T.pack()
    T.insert(tk.END, "Hello World")
    tk.mainloop()


>>> def launch_thread():
    print("Function called")
    thread = threading.Thread(target=build_textbox)
    print("Thread created")
    thread.start()
    print("After start")
    thread.join()
    print("Success")


>>> launch_thread()
Function called
Thread created
After start
Success
>>> launch_thread()
Function called
Thread created
```

Comment: You need to be calling `root.mainloop()` for a start... There are many things that need to be changed in this code. Tkinter should be programmed slighty differently when using an interactive shell.